# Linear transformation, a doubt, two cases.

Tags: linear-algebra

Good afternoon. I have doubts on how to verify it or not this is a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{C(R)}\rightarrow\mathbb{C(R})$ defined by: $T(f(x))=\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}$. Where $\mathbb{C(R)}$ represents the set of continuous functions in $\mathbb{R}$.

My work:

I feel that to prove this, I have to consider two cases, the first if the function $f(x)$is even, in this case it must $T(f(x))=f(x)$ and this would be the identity operator, which is linear. And in the second case, if the function $f(x)$ is odd, since it would have to $T(f(x))=0$ and this is the null operator, which is linear. I do not know if I'm right, my biggest problem is to write this exercise well. If there is another way to demonstrate the linearity and want to share I would be very grateful.

Comment: No, you are going the wrong way: by reasoning on $f$ such that $T(f)=0$, you are already implicitly assuming that $T$ is linear... All you have to do is to check the two defining properties $T(f_1+f_2)=T(f_1)+T(f_2)$ and $T(af)=aT(f)$.

Comment: @JeanMarie But I can not bear the fact that f can be odd or even?

Comment: No need. Apply blindly the definition. For example proving that $T(af)=aT(f)$ means proving that $\dfrac{(af)(x)+(af)(-x)}{2}$ is equal to $a \dfrac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}$... rather evident, no ?

Comment: Moreover, a big warning: either a function is even, or is odd, OR is nothing of these (as is the case for most functions...).

Comment: @JeanMarie That is you say, that the definition applies only to test the linearity and does not consider any cases?

Comment: Yes,  That's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we go by given definition then 
$$T((f+g)(x)) = \frac{(f+g)(x) + (f+g)(-x)}{2} = \frac{(f(x)+ g(x)) + (f(-x)+g(-x))}{2} = \frac{f(x) + f(-x)}{2} + \frac{g(x)+ g(-x)}{2} = T(f(x)) + T(g(x)) $$
as desired. Similarly one may show homogeneity.

Answer (score 3):

To verify that $T$ is a linear transformation you can use the definition and verify that

$$T(f+\lambda g)=T(f)+\lambda T(g)$$
for $f,g\in \mathcal C(\Bbb R)$ and $\lambda\in\Bbb R$. You may also notice that $\mathcal C(\Bbb R)=\mathcal E(\Bbb R)\oplus\mathcal O(\Bbb R)$ where $\mathcal E(\Bbb R)$ is the subspace of even functions and $\mathcal O(\Bbb R)$ is the subspace of odd function and that $T$ is nothing but the projection onto $\mathcal E(\Bbb R)$ parallel to $\mathcal O(\Bbb R)$.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments of your post, the most straightforward way to do that is to blindly apply the definition. But I wish to specify that in a linear algebra context reasoning the way you did isn't completely wrong. We can proove that  $\mathscr{C}(\mathbb{R}) = \mathscr{F}_{even}(\mathbb{R}) \bigoplus \mathscr{F}_{odd}(\mathbb{R})$ $(*)$ and if you proove T to be linear on both the sub vectorial spaces then it is linear on $\mathscr{C}(\mathbb{R})$ But it definetly isn't efficient if the problem didn't talk about $(*)$

Comment: You would also have to prove that $T(g_e+g_o)= T(g_e)+T(g_o)$ for any $g_e$ even and any $g_o$ odd function.

Comment: You are right. My point though was not ruling out the useful point of view of seeing a vector space as a big O sum of two friendlier sub vector spaces